# How to convert float to 4byte hex string in JavaScript and turn back?

Tags: javascript, hex, byte

I get an hexadecimal data from server side, but it is some `float`, so I want to convert these hexadecimal to `float`, but I can't find any method in JavaScript. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show an example of the hex string input, and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused with your wording but if you're trying to convert a float to a hexadecimal string try:

```
hex = floatNum.toString(16);
```